# why this lowercase function in C give me segfault memory error?

Tags: segmentation-fault, c99

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char* my_downcase(char* param_1) {
   int c = 0;

   while (param_1[c] != '\0') {
      if (param_1[c] >= 'A' && param_1[c] <= 'Z') {
         param_1[c] = param_1[c] + 32;
      }
      c++;
   }
   printf("%s", param_1);
   return param_1;
}

int main(){
    char *r = "ABC";
    char *res = my_downcase(r);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm lower casing using asci table. But when i compile and run it , it gives me segfault error, why?

Comment: By the way, thanks for posting a complete reproducible example.  You seemed to be assuming the problem was with your `my_downcase` function, but in fact the function itself is fine, and the problem was with what you are passing to it.  If you'd only posted the function you thought was causing the problem, we'd never have identified the issue.

Comment: @NateEldredge thx u for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointer `r` is pointing to a string literal, and string literals are not allowed to be modified.

Try instead

`char r[] = "ABC";`

which will make `r` an ordinary array which you can modify, initialized with the string `"ABC"`.